# imshow for 3D? (Python / Matplotlib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

does there exist an equivalent to matplotlib's imshow()-function for 3D-drawing of datas stored in a 3D numpy array?

Answer (score 6):

This is ill-defined, since how would you see stuff that was not at the surface of the cube?

The Mayavi documentation has various approaches of ways to do what you want to do, including cut planes and voxel-specific alpha channels. See [visualizing volumetric scalar data](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html).

Suffice it to say this requires [Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/index.html) and is rather beyond the scope of matplotlib's (handy, but limited) 3D features.

Answer (score 4):

matplotlib cannot plot 3d image. you can use [mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [mplot3d](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/index.html) to plot 3D objects. [Here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/subplot3d_demo.html) is one of the example codes.

Comment: the point is, that I don't have a function to plot but for each pixel (x,y,z) a value stored in the 3d-array. Therefore I cannot use either the suggested function nor the surface-plot one.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a kind of 3D image (a block). Maybe you could plot it by slices (using imshow() or whatever the tool you want).

Maybe you could tell us what kind of plot you want?