# Is there a 3d plotting function similar to Axes.imshow()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Ive got test MRI data that I would like to make a 3D plot of. Right now I am visualising each slice individually though using the `axes.imshow()` function. Is there a 3d equivalent?

Taking the following example, is there anyway to get a black cube out of `data` in the following example, as opposed to just black square slices of it? That will solve my issue.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.zeros((200,200,200))

slice_0 = data[0,:,:]

fig,axes = plt.subplots()

axes.imshow(slice_0.T, cmap="gray")
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjc3J.png)

Comment: I think your issue is solved here: [Plotting 3d image from a data in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663597/plotting-3d-image-form-a-data-in-numpy-array) Hope this helps!